# Example of a number field with only one complex place

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In a number theory textbook they are asking for a field $F$ which has only one complex place.

Can $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ ?  Can $F$ be or arbitrary degree?

Comment: Could you remind me, please, the relationship between valuation and place in a number field?. I don't remember clearly about this.

Comment: Adjoin a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree n with n-2 real roots.

Comment: Considering a place as an equivalence class of absolute values and that the prime field $\mathbb Q$ admits for each prime $p$ a p-adic absolute value all of them non equivalent each other, it is maybe in characteristic $p$ where there is a solution? Am I wrong with this (doubtfully) reasoning?.

Comment: @Piquito, OP is asking about archimedean places.

Comment: @Lubin: Very kind. Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not come back to the definition of a complex place? If $F$ is a number field of degree $n = r + 2c$, where $r$ is the number of real embeddings and $2c$ the number of conjugate complex embeddings, then the number of complex places is $c$. This gives you as many examples as you want of number fields with a single complex place.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Nguyen Quang Do is perfect, but let me be more specific. If you have a $\Bbb Q$-irreducible polynomial $f$ with only one pair of complex roots, then for $\alpha$ an abstract root of $f$, $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ has only one complex place.

Examples: $f(X)=X^3-m$ for squarefree $m\,$; also $X^5-27X+3$.

Don’t forget: in a *Galois* extension of $\Bbb Q$, the archimedean places are either all real or all complex. So the only Galois extensions with only one complex place are the imaginary quadratic ones.

Comment: it's not so easy verify polynomial has one one do complex pair of roots and the rest real rooms. But perhaps can be done as you're showing.

Comment: Basic methods of Calculus will usually allow one to sketch the graph well enough to count the real roots, I think.